# Show that $0\leq c_1n^2\leq an^2+bn+c \leq c_2 n^2$ for all $n\geq n_0.$

Tags: inequality, computational-complexity

Currently I am reading [Introduction to Algorithm](https://www.bookdepository.com/Introduction-to-Algorithms-Thomas-H.-Cormen/9780262033848?redirected=true&utm_medium=Google&utm_campaign=Base1&utm_source=SG&utm_content=Introduction-to-Algorithms&selectCurrency=SGD&w=AF7JAU99N4CQU6A80T12&pdg=pla-317692435101:cmp-6485098310:adg-77818344677:crv-381246268071:pos-:dev-c&gclid=CjwKCAjwq4fsBRBnEiwANTahcIkE-MMpukH8Z6THRxiS5lfnj_oL7rZkKM6S9fTlKW7rvBkoW44R-xoC4I0QAvD_BwE).
At page $46,$ the author mentions the following.

> Let $f(n) = an^2+bn+c$ where $a>0.$ 
>   If $c_1 = \frac{a}{4}, c_2 = \frac{7a}{4}$ and $n_0 = 2\max \{\frac{|b|}{a}, \sqrt{\frac{|c|}{a}} \},$ then one may verify that 
>   $$0\leq c_1n^2\leq an^2+bn+c \leq c_2 n^2 \quad \text{for all } n\geq n_0.$$

I am not able to verify the above inequalities.

For example, we would like to have 
$$c_1 n^2 \leq an^2+bn+c,$$
which is equivalent to 
$$0 \leq \frac{3an^2}{4} + bn + c.$$
But I do not know how to apply the fact that $n\geq 2 \max \{\frac{|b|}{a}, \sqrt{\frac{|c|}{a}} \}.$

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I believe I can help you answer your question, but I first need to confirm a potential small mistake. You have $f(n) = an^2 + bn + c$, but in your verification question, and just below it in your example, the quadratic you state is $n^2 + bn + c$. However, in the line below that where you state it's "equivalent to", the result comes from using $an^2 + bn + c$. My initial work on answering this indicates it should have a leading term of $an^2$.  Nonetheless, first please confirm what the appropriate quadratic to use is, such as by updating your question text. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnOmielan That is a small typo. Thanks for pointing out. Edited my post.

Comment: You're welcome for pointing it out. However, you only corrected the typo in one place. The last part of the yellow text still has that typo.

Comment: Thanks for making this additional fix. One other small typo is in your second last line, where it should be $n \geq 2\max \{\frac{|b|}{a}, \sqrt{\frac{|c|}{a}} \}$, i.e., you're missing the factor of $2$.

Answer (score 1):

You are given a quadratic function and several related constants of

$$f(n) = an^2+bn+c, \; a \gt 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

$$c_1 = \frac{a}{4}, \; c_2 = \frac{7a}{4} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

$$n_0 = 2\max \left\{\frac{|b|}{a}, \sqrt{\frac{|c|}{a}} \right\} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

You're asked to verify that

$$0 \leq c_1n^2 \leq an^2 + bn + c \leq c_2n^2 \quad \text{for all } n \geq n_0 \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

Since $c_1 \gt 0$, then the first part of \eqref{eq4}, i.e., $0 \le c_1n^2$, is quite obviously true.  The next part is to show that

$$c_1n^2 \le an^2 + bn + c \implies 0 \le \frac{3an^2}{4} + bn + c \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

as you've already noted. I will show \eqref{eq5} holds for all $n \geq n_0$ using $2$ basic steps: confirm it holds at $n_0$, and the RHS never becomes less than $0$ for any later value. For the second step, there are $2$ main ways I'm aware of doing this: determine the derivative of the RHS is always non-negative for $n \geq n_0$, or use the quadratic formula to show there are no roots, the roots are all less than $n_0$, or there is a repeated root at or after $n_0$. To help keep this answer somewhat simpler, and since I believe you know how to use derivatives, I'll just use the derivative method here. This gives

$$g(n) = \frac{3an}{2} + b \; \text{ and } \; g'(n) = \frac{3a}{2} \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

Since $a \ge 0$, \eqref{eq6} is an increasing function, as indicated by $g'(n) \gt 0$, so if you can show it's non-negative at $n = n_0$, it'll always be non-negative for all $n \ge n_0$, so the original function will always be non-decreasing and, thus, non-negative if it starts that way.

From \eqref{eq3}, there are $2$ cases to consider based on which value inside the curly brackets is larger. First, consider

$$\frac{|b|}{a} \ge \sqrt{\frac{|c|}{a}} \tag{7}\label{eq7}$$

so $n_0 = \frac{2|b|}{a}$. The RHS of \eqref{eq5} for $n = n_0$ becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{3an^2}{4} + bn + c & = \frac{3a(4b^2)}{4a^2} + \frac{2b|b|}{a} + c \\
& = \frac{3b^2}{a} + \frac{2b|b|}{a} + c \\
& \ge \frac{b^2}{a} + c
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{8}\label{eq8}$$

The last step comes from $\frac{2b|b|}{a} >= -\frac{2b^2}{a}$, with equality if $b \le 0$. Next, as both values in \eqref{eq7} are non-negative, you can square both sides and keep the same inequality, so doing this & some manipulations gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{b^2}{a^2} \ge \frac{|c|}{a} \\
\frac{b^2}{a} \ge |c| \\
\frac{b^2}{a} \ge -c \\
\frac{b^2}{a} + c \ge 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{9}\label{eq9}$$

This, along with \eqref{eq8} shows the RHS of \eqref{eq5} holds for $n = n_0$. Next, \eqref{eq6} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
g(n_0) & = \frac{3a(2|b|)}{a} + b \\
& = 6|b| + b \\
& \ge 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{10}\label{eq10}$$

You can use a similar procedure for the second case of \eqref{eq3} (i.e., show the RHS of \eqref{eq5} holds for $\frac{|b|}{a} \lt \sqrt{\frac{|c|}{a}}$), and then repeat both steps for the final part of \eqref{eq4}, i.e., to show that $an^2 + bn + c \le c_2n^2$. I'll leave these remaining steps to you to do.

Comment: Why is equation $g(n)$ in equation $(6)$ nonnegative?

Comment: @Idonknow Equation (6)'s $g(n)$ is non-negative for $n \ge n_0$ because I've shown that it's $\ge 0$ for $n = n_0$ and, as it's $g(n) = \frac{3an}{2} + b$, then any larger value of $n$ will make the result larger since $a \gt 0$, so $g(n)$ will actually always be strictly positive for $n \gt n_0$. In particular, if $n_1 \gt n_0$, then $g(n_1) - g(n_0) = \left(\frac{3an_1}{2} + b\right) - \left(\frac{3an_0}{2} + b\right) = \frac{3a(n_1 - n_0)}{2} \gt 0$, so $g(n_1) \gt g(n_0)$.

Comment: @Idonknow More simply, equation (6)'s $g(n)$ has $g'(n) = \frac{3a}{2} \gt 0$, as I've updated my answer to show & use.

Answer (score 1):

If $a>0$ and $n\geq1$ then
$$an^2+bn+c=n^2\left(a+{b\over n}+{c\over n^2}\right)\left\{\eqalign{&>{a\over4}n^2\cr &<{7a\over4}n^2\cr}\right.\quad,$$
as soon as $n$ is chosen so large that
$${|b|\over n}<{a\over2}\qquad\wedge\qquad {|c|\over n^2}<{a\over4}\ .$$
This is fulfilled if
$$n>n_0:=2\max\left\{{|b|\over a},\sqrt{{|c|\over a}}\right\}\ .$$